# Finding intermediate values

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can you help me to figure out how this outout emerged?

> A sequence of $N$ data points as a list of comma separated integer values.
>
> Task is generate $N$ values representing the original values, but obfuscating their real values.
>
> You should do this by selecting the highest and lowest value in the data set and creating $N - 2$ data points numerically evenly spaced out between the two. Your output should be a comma separated list of $N$ integer values ordered from low to high. Where the numbers are not integer, you should round them such that they end up integer.

```
Example 1:
Input: "3,2"

Output: "2,3"
```

> **Explanation:** The lowest and highest values are $3$ and $4$ respectively, and there are no intermediate values that need to be interpreted

```
Example 2:
Input: "4,5,3,5"

Output: "3,4,4,5"
```

> **Explanation:** The lowest and highest values are $3$ and $5$ and the intermediate values become $3.66$ and $4.33$, which when rounded to integers to make as $4$ and $4$.

Comment: You’ll probably have to give more context. This is apparently from some algorithm; what is the algorithm supposed to be doing?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example there are $4$ data points, the smallest being $3$ and the largest $5$. Thus, we want to produce $4$ equally spaced points $3,a,b,5$.

The gap between $3$ and $5$ is $5-3=2$ units long, and we want to put $2$ points into it. Those $2$ points create $3$ gaps, which are all supposed to be the same length: $$a-3=b-a=5-b\;.$$ This means that the gap between consecutive points must be one-third of the length of the interval from $3$ to $5$, i.e., $\dfrac{5-3}3=\dfrac23$. That puts $a$ at $3+\dfrac23\approx 3.67$ and $b$ at $3+2\cdot\dfrac23=3+\dfrac43\approx4.33$, both of which round to $4$.

In general if $m$ is your smallest data point, and $M$ is your largest, you’ll be finding $N-2$ equally spaced points between $m$ and $M$. Those points will create $N-1$ equal-sized gaps, so the size of each gap must be $\dfrac{M-m}{N-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Once one knows $N$ the length of the input, $m$ its minimum value and $M$ its maximum value, the output is $(x_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant N}$ where $x_k$ is the nearest integer to $\dfrac{(N-k)m+M(k-1)}{N-1}$.